# Can I use OpenOCD to identify the instructions responsible for an user-triggered feature on a device with an stm32f4 processor?

Tags: stm32, reverse-engineering, trace, stm32f4, openocd

The device in question is a ResMed 10 PaceWave ASV, an advanced Positive Airway Pressure ventilator.

There was a project early in the pandemic to convert ResMed 10 devices to emergency ventilators, which, while abandoned, produced a working jailbreak, and the know-how
necessary to work with the firmware.

What I would like to do, is to identify the instruction(s) responsible for triggering machine-initiated breaths when one pauses breathing, as the feature is dysfunctional for a lot of patients, myself included, and heavily compromises sleep quality.

Answer (score -1):

Apart that I think the question is off-topic and too general, try to find what gpio pilots the ventilation with a scope and then search with a disassembler access to the ODR or MODER gpio registers for that PORT/PIN. That should bring down your search to few spots. You can even try to simulate the thing on renode.